# Excel IF AND Statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have the IF AND Statement below and value in Cell A1 is 10 but the statement is returning blank.

```
=IF(AND(A1>1, A1<20,((A1/10)*5)), "")
```

Answer (score 5):

Brackets:

```
=IF(AND(A1>1, A1<20),(A1/10)*5,"")
```

Your formula was evaluated like this:

```
A1>1  => TRUE
A1<20 => TRUE
2     => TRUE
""
```

If you've entered `21` in `A1` your formula would result in `FALSE`.